# Two Instagram business accounts linked. Posting from the first and it ends up on facebook for the second

Tags: instagram

I am asking this questions for my employer. She has two businesses. Both have Instagram business accounts and Facebook business pages. She is posting on Instagram account number one and when she shares with Facebook it is sharing with account number number two's Facebook page. She tried to unlink the Instagram business accounts to temporarily solve the problem but she finds the option in Instagram settings to unlink and presses it to follow the prompts to unlink but then it doesn't unlink them. How can I help her fix this problem?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not **[about a website you control](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)**. This *may* be a better fit at [webapps.se]. Be sure to read their [FAQ](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/help) before posting to make sure your question meets their requirements.